# Angular 2 AuthGuard throws me out whenever I am making a http get request

Tags: angular, authentication, angular6, angular2-routing, auth-guard

I have one angular application a simple dashboard which I have built in Angular 6. Now I am trying to add login and authentication so for this I have created one AuthGuard

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class RouteGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url }});
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in app-routing I have configured my routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path:'home', component: MatBoardComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuard] },
    {path:'http', component: HttpCallComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuard] },
    {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
    {path:'**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

So whenever I click on any link when I am not logged in my RouteGuard redirects me back to login but with successful login I am able to access the page.
The problem I am facing is whenever I click on http link there I have a form and on the submission of that form I am making a http request to git. This is my HttpCallComponent's html

```
<div class="grid-container">
<form #SimpleForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="userName">User Name: </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" required [(ngModel)] = "model.userName" 
      name="userName" #userName="ngModel">
      <div [hidden] ="userName.valid || userName.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
          User name is required
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="sourceName">Source: </label>
      <select class="form-control" id="sourceName" [(ngModel)] = "model.sourceName" name="courseName">
          <option *ngFor="let course of sourceName" [value]="course">{{course}}</option>
      </select>
  </div> 
</form>

<button class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!SimpleForm.form.valid" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit Form</button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="response" [@fadeInOut]>
    <p>Login Name: {{response.login}}</p>
    <p>Followers: {{response.followers}}</p>
    <p>Public Repos: {{response.public_repos}}</p>
    <p>Avatar:</p>
    <img src={{response.avatar_url}} style="max-height: 150px">
</div>
```

and in .ts I am making call to git

```
onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.model.sourceName);
    if(this.model.sourceName == 'GIT'){
      this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/'+this.model.userName)
      .subscribe ((response) => {
        this.response = response;
        console.log(this.response);
      }
        )
    }
```

So as I click on submit I am being redirected to login page. Please assist me where I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I think I found the issue so this is my interceptor which is adding extra authorization to github user api call.

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add authorization header with jwt token if available
        let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: { 
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`
                }
            });
        }

        return next.handle(request);
    }
```

For me I just want interceptor to skip https://api.github.com/users/ call and it should not add any authorization to it so can you please assist me skipping any particular url.

Comment: I don't get why this is an AuthGuard problem. Where are you performing navigation?

Comment: Do you have a http interceptor running?

Comment: @AndrewAllen No I don't have any interceptor running. So earlier when I didn't had AuthGuard my http calls were working properly without any issue. I am having this problem since I have added AuthGuard.

Comment: @KurtHamilton I am only clicking on form and submitting 2 fields(User name and source which is GIT) which I have used to make http get call from GIT and displaying back that result on UI using response object. My http call is just fetching details from GIT of the user entered via UI

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in a stackblitz or show more relevant code

Comment: @KurtHamilton Sure I will add my code as much as I can in stackblitz after some time

Comment: AndrewAllen and KurtHamilton please take a look at the edit and suggest solution